# What's the best technique for farming melons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got some melon seeds from an abandoned mine chest. I naively planted them as I would wheat seeds, in a patch of grass, altogether. I came back to find that they'd matured into fully grown plants, but there wasn't a melon to be seen. What should I be doing?

Comment: I thought they branch out.  Haven't you ever seen melons or squash (pumpkins) growing in real life?

Comment: Wait, you're comparing Minecraft to real life?

Comment: None of those work anymore because of 1.1, now you cant place seeds adjacent to each other anymore. :( its really glitchy soz my seeds always disappear for some reason.

Comment: @EpicTreeko You might be having the same problem I had, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38570/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-this-seed-planting-bug

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To grow Melons, you need Farmland to plant the Melon Seeds in, and dirt, farmland, or grass blocks adjacent to those where the Melons can grow onto. Melons grow slowly until their stem grows to the maximum size, at which point a Melon grows on a suitable block adjacent to where the stem grew out of (where you planted the seed). The Minecraft Wiki page on Melons has a [nice section on farming them](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon_%28Block%29#Farming). They suggest using an arrangement like this:

```
S S S S S S S S S |
# # # # # # # # # |
# # # # # # # # # | S = Watermelon seed
S S S S S S S S S | # = Dirt/Grass/Farmland
S S S S W S S S S | W = Water block
# # # # X # # # # | X = Random block
# # # # # # # # # |
S S S S S S S S S |
```

Comment: Note, unless you like waiting on melons to grow, you might find it better to arrange your melons where you're less likely to trample the vine. They can die if their dirt changes from fertile soil to regular dirt, and it's rather a pointless waste. =)

Comment: Now that trampling has been removed in 1.1, this isn't a concern, but it's still an issue for those on older versions.

Comment: Note that melon and pumpkin stems no longer need adjacent Farmland for the gourd to grow onto. Any ol' block will do now.

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use the same method I used w/ wheat but w/melons. I think this is the quickest way to harvest any plant. I'm the type that likes to build my farms underground so here's my technique:

```
# # # # # # # # #|
S S S S S S S S S| # = Farmland
W W W W W W W S #| S = Seeds
S S S S S S S S S| W = Water
# # # # # # # # #|
```

Note: The dirt blocks are placed 1 block above ground level to prevent stepping on the farmland and the torches are placed 1 block level above the seeds except for the two on the far right side.

Answer (score 0):

This is the weirdest answer you'll get.

```
I I I I I I I I I |  I = Cobblestone with two iron bars on top
I S S S S S S S I |  S = Watermelon seed
I # # # S # # # I |  # = Dirt (not farmland)
I S S S G S S S I |  G = Glass block
I # # # S # # # I |
I S S S S S S S I |
I I I I I I I I I |
```

Comment: Can you edit the answer to explain why this setup should be used?

Comment: This looks intriguing, but it would be great to know why this works so well.

Comment: If you are actively harvesting, I can see this being compact and efficient, as each dirt block has 2-4 stems adjacent to it. But If you want to go do other stuff and only harvest when you need melons, the yield per harvest is quite low. Additionally, the diagram has 2 seeds that are surrounded on all 4 sides by non-open dirt and are useless.

Answer (score -2):

```
W # W W # W W # W W # W | S = Watermelon seed
# S # # S # # S # # S # | # = Farmland
W # W W # W W # W W # W | W = Water block
W # W W # W W # W W # W |
# S # # S # # S # # S # |
W # W W # W W # W W # W |
W # W W # W W # W W # W |
# S # # S # # S # # S # |
W # W W # W W # W W # W |
```

I found this to be the most efficient way to farm melons.

Comment: You don't need nearly that many water blocks to water all the farmland.

Comment: That is an incredibly inefficient use of space.  You can easily double the density of seeds without sacrificing production efficiency.