# Is there any way to avoid this seed planting bug?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am experiencing a very annoying bug where planting two seeds next to each other causes them to either turn back into items, or disappear entirely. This happens for wheat, pumpkin, and melon seeds in the same area.

If I try to plant wheat in the red square (Image 1), then both it and the one next to it disappear (Image 2).

[image: Before planting]
[image: After planting]

Is there anything I can do to stop this happening and plant my seeds properly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It looks to me that it isn't a bug that's causing the seeds to pop out, but your lack of lighting. If an area is too dark, seeds will pop out. I don't know why the other one pops out too, but you can at least try to increase the lighting. That should fix the problem.

Comment: The reason is that many plants (including wheat and mushrooms, that I'm aware of) can be *planted* in unsuitable lighting conditions, but won't *stay* there if a block update occurs.  What's happening here is that the next-to-last square is too dark, but the wheat stays there until the next seed is planted, which causes the next-to-last to update and pop off, which causes the last to update and pop off.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem, when i would plant seeds, they would pop off. Its the lighting, as you may need to add a torch or glowstone above the dirt, and it should fix this issue. By the way, to make a torch be in the center, you build a small tower, about 3 high, (depending on the ceiling) then 1-2 blocks to where the center of the dirt and crops are, then you place torches on the block(s) and remove the tower.